# How to set up Jaspersoft's iRreport to send automated .pdf emails?

Tags: reporting

I read somewhere that it was possible to have iReport send your reports via email? Is this at all possible and how is it done?

Comment: Being a purely technical question, I am afraid this is out of scope here. Depending on the nature of said product, your question may belong to StackOverflow or SuperUser. Please don't cross-post though - wait for other people's opinion (and votes) and moderator's word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this through Jasper Server.

http://www.jaspersoft.com/configuring-report-scheduler

Above link shows you how to configure the mail settings of the server.. Then it's simply setting up the schedule of the report (right click the report through your browser and click schedule)

Answer (score 1):

The way I have done it is using iReport to write the report, JasperReport Server to store the report, and then a cron job launching a python script using pyjaser. Now this was already in a system that had jasper report setup. I didn't go through all this trouble for just one report.

Comment: This wouldn't be for just one report. It would be for multiple reports. Thank you for the response!